# How to create javascript array based on user input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've dynamically loading check box fields, how can I send those to server based on user selection.

For example I've following doc,

```
<label>Set1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Apple" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Mango" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Grape" />

<label>Set2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="set_200[]" value="Red" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_200[]" value="Blue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_200[]" value="Orange" />
```

Suppose if user selected first two values for each of them, then I need to send like

```
response[0][0]=199; // Id
response[0][1]=['Apple','Mango']; //values
response[1][0]=200
response[1][1]=['Red','Blue'];
```

I've tried some approaches suggested in existing posts but failed to implement how I want.

Comment: I think not <lable> -> <label>

Comment: can you make some minor markup changes

Comment: which server scripting are u using?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Sure, please suggest.

Comment: @Arvind: I using PHP, but I've problem in creating array of selected values with its id. Not in sending to server.

Comment: Why? Why would you go through all that trouble, instead of sending the form fields to the server, where you can access all data like so (assume using POST): `echo $_POST['set_199'][0], $_POST['set_199'][1]` , which in your example will echo `AppleMango`. As an added bonus: clients who've disabled JS will still be able to use your site :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Actually I don't have form at this point otherwise I would done the same as you have suggested. I'm sending this to server using AJAX.

Comment: Even so, make a form, and use `yourForm.elements` to build an object literal, and send that...

Comment: @Mahesh.D: I've posted an example of this as an answer, including a fiddle version

Answer (score 3):

You can make some minor changes in the html then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
<label class="set" data-id="199">Set1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Apple" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Mango" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Grape" />
<label class="set" data-id="200">Set2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="set_200[]" value="Red" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_200[]" value="Blue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_200[]" value="Orange" />
```

then

```
var array = $('.set').map(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.data('id'),
        array = [id];

    array.push($('input[name="set_' + id + '\\[\\]"]').filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get())
    return [array]
}).get()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7MA65/)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
<lable>Set1</lable>
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Apple" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Mango" />
<input type="checkbox" name="set_199[]" value="Grape" />

<input type="button" value="check" class="js-submit">
```

Js:

```
$(".js-submit").on("click", function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    var values = {};
    a.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        if(!values[name]) values[name] = [];
        values[name].push(value)
    });
    console.log(values)
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6775b/)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment a little, here's how I'd do this... given that you're sending this as an ajax request, I'd still wrap these elements in a form element, and use that as a starting-point to build the object we'll be sending...

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('formID').elements,//get all input nodes
data = {},temp;
for (var i=0;i<myForm.length;++i)
{
    temp = myForm.item(i).name.replace(/[[]]/g,'');//replace square brackets
    if (!data[temp])
        data[temp] = [];//create array if key does not exist
    if (myForm.item(i).checked)//for checkboxes
        data[temp].push(myForm.item(i).value);
}
```

That's the basic setup. If you want, you can add checks and further tailor this, so you can deal with various types of input fields, but in essence, it'll boil down to this.
You might also want to use `Array.prototype.forEach` on the `myForm.elements` NodeList, and use a callback to keep your code nice and clean.
Here's an example of a slightly more usable version of the same code:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    var data = {};
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(frm.elements, function(item)
    {
        var temp;
        if (item === btn) return;//don't includ the button element
        if (item.type === 'checkbox' && !item.checked ) return;//not checked, ignore
        if (item.name.match(/[[]]/))
        {
            temp = item.name.replace(/[[]]/g, '');
            if (!data[temp]) data[temp] = [];//if property does not exist, make an array
            data[temp].push(item.value);
            return;
        }
        //normal elements:
        data[item.name] = item.value;
    });
    //ajax request using data variable goes here!
    console.log(data);
},false);
```

## And [here's the fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/a48TU/)

Comment: I'm unable to workout on your solution, please don't mind. Once again thanks for your effort on my foolish question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for all who have given answers to this question. I've derived my own solution for this issue but it is not possible without your help, especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699836/1111502)

```
       var checkBoxArray = {};

        $.each($("input[name^='set_'][type='checkbox']:checked"), function(i, item) {

            var Id = item.name.replace(/^(set_)|[\[\]]/g, "");
            var value = $(item).val();         

            if(!checkBoxArray[Id]) 
               checkBoxArray[Id] = [];
             checkBoxArray[Id].push(value)
        });                        

         $.map(checkBoxArray, function(value, index) {
           reponse.push([index, value]);
         });
```

Its worked for me, suggest if anything not proper in above code snippet.

Comment: You can use .map from EcmaScript 5))

Comment: @FUserThrowError: Is it good in terms of performance than each ?